# Changing TBitBtn Glyph at runtime

Tags: vcl, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I have a VCL form with a TBitBtn on it and an TImageList containing 2 bitmaps. At runtime i run the following line of code to put one of the bitmaps on my TBitBtn:

```
ImageList1->GetBitmap(1, BitBtn1->Glyph);
```

This succesfully puts the bitmap on the TBitBtn.  Then later i run the following line of code to change the bitmap and nothing happens:

```
ImageList1->GetBitmap(0, BitBtn1->Glyph);
```

Both bitmaps are present in the imagelist (0 and 1).  I can swap the lines of code and prove nothing wrong with the imagelist.    [Here is](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=211573) an old post where a guy seems to solve this in Delphi. I'm thinking i must need to somehow clear the Glyph first but i don't know how in C++.

Comment: Hi Ken.  No, `BitBtn1->Refresh();` had no affect.

Comment: Yeah, didn't work in Delphi either. What did work was creating a local TBitmap, using SetSize(ImageList1.Width, ImageList1.Height), replacing `BitBtn1.Glyph` with that bitmap in the call to GetBitmap, and then using `BitBtn1.Glyph.Assign` passing my temporary bitmap. Surround it with a try..finally (or the Builder equivalent) to free that temp bitmap.

Comment: Ken - thank you. I'm not sure how to do that in C++.  In the meantime i changed my approach and just saved my 2 bitmaps to local files.  Then i can assign them to the BitBtn with one line of code like this: `BitBtn1->Glyph->LoadFromFile("t:\\testdir\\first.bmp");`   As infrequently as these will be used it should be fine.

Comment: One more thing, i'll end up just deploying the 2 bitmaps in the application folder so i'll use something like this:  `BitBtn1->Glyph->LoadFromFile(GetCurrentDir() + "\\first.bmp";`

Comment: In Delphi7, the glyph changes on screen only if you Nil it before the new assignment (no repaint/refresh/redraw do the trick) `BitBtn1.Glyph := Nil; ImageList1.GetBitmap(1, BitBtn1.Glyph);` so perhaps in C++ you should try the same `BitBtn1->Glyph = NULL;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of one way to use it, using a temporary `TBitmap` to retrieve the image from the `TImageList` and put it into the glyph at runtime. It does so in this example on the `TBitBtn->OnClick` event handler.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::btn1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    // FOdd is a bool variable defined in the form's private section.
    // It's just being used here as a toggle to flip between the images
    this->FOdd = !this->FOdd;

    TBitmap *bmp = new Graphics::TBitmap();
    try {
        bmp->SetSize(this->ImageList1->Width, this->ImageList1->Height);
        this->ImageList1->GetBitmap(int(FOdd), bmp);
        this->BitBtn1->Glyph->Assign(bmp);
    }
    __finally
    {
        delete bmp;
    }    
}
```

@relayman357 provided the proper code for the try..__finally block to make this answer more suitable.

Comment: @relayman357: Thanks for the edit. I'll do a little cleanup. :-)